# Swing code to copy label along with text

Tags: java, swing

I have the below code that will copy text entered in `JtextArea` to clipboard.
But, is it possible to copy text in `Jlabel` along with `JTextArea`?

I have "User" in `JLabel`, can I copy it along wiht `JTextArea`, something like below

User:"data entered in `JTextArea`"

```
private void UsercopyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   String get= hActionText.getText();
   StringSelection Queue= new StringSelection(get);
   Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
   clipboard.setContents(Queue, Queue);
}
```

Comment: you can add the label content to your String before the stringselection.

Comment: what do you mean 'copy the JTextArea'? how are you going to copy a textarea? do you mean the text in it? or the object itself?

Comment: @ItamarGreen sorry, I mean the text in text area..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply use `get=label.getText()+get;` before `StringSelection Queue= new StringSelection(get);` this will add the labels text before the data

Comment: I dint expect it would be so simple. Do you mind letting me know, how do I add "colon" after label? like User : "text"

Comment: if its not in the label itself use this `get=label.getText()+":"+get;` instead of the other code